# compiler error: Expected: end of statement when using "To" statement for array range excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, statements

For a project I am working on I'm using a param array to grab string values from a user and then run an autofilter incorporating string values from the array. However, whenever I use a `To` statement(E.G. `Boundaries = LBound(ArrayHere) To UBound(ArrayHere)`) I get the following error:

**Screenshot:**
[image: Compiler Error when using "To" statement in variable.]

**Code:**

```
Sub FilterWorkbookByServiceCode(FileName As String, WorkSheetName As String, Start As String, EndColumn As String, Field As Integer, ParamArray Numbers() As Variant)

    Dim Boundaries As Long

    Boundaries = LBound(Numbers) To Ubound(Numbers) 'Line Compiler error occurs on.

    Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(WorkSheetName).Activate
    Range(Start).End(xlDown).Select
    Range(EndColumn & ActiveCell.Row).Select


    With Range(Start & ":" & ActiveCell.Address)
        .Select
        .AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=Numbers(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm stumped on what I should do to correct this issue so any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

To be a bit more clear, I'm trying to get the range of the param array, and then store it in a variable. I need to find the range of the array dyanmically as the user can input varying amount of values into the array, and then call each value from the array to use as the criteria for the autofilter.

Comment: I assume you are doing a loop.  `For Boundaries = LBound(ArrayHere) To UBound(ArrayHere)`

Comment: And then add `Next Boundaries` where you want the loop to reach, and repeat.

Comment: Though I need to able to apply multiple values to the autofilter criteria. A loop won't work because as it goes through the loop the value for the criteria gets written with only one of the values from the array each time.

Comment: So you wand Boundaries to be a count of the Array? `Boundaries =  Ubound(Numbers) +1`

Comment: Or do you want an Boundaries to be a copy of the Numbers Array?

Comment: Yes. I need to be able to pull all values from the array. However, the amount of values inputted by the user is going to vary.

Comment: Pull the values and put them where?  By your code you do not even need the line that is giving troubles.  You do not use it anywhere.  Try deleting the line and see what happens.

Comment: So usually in the autofilter criteria you'd put in the value you want to filter for. When you want to filter multiple values you'd do the following:  `Criteria1:=Array(Numbers(0), Numbers(1), Numbers(N)...)`. However, since I can't tell how many values the user is going to try filtering for, I need to figure out a way to dynamically adjust the range of values the array is calling for the autofilter, or get the range of the param array and call that range for the autofilter criteria.

Comment: You can see the answer I posted and let me know if it helps or if you have any questions post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `boundaries` used after that statement. So, remove the statement that is causing the error.

Pass numbers to your function in quotes.
i.e.

`FilterMySheetWithTheseValues("1","2",3")` where it is defined as

```
Sub FilterMySheetWithTheseValues(paramarray numbers() as variant)
   Range("A1:A10").AutoFilter 1, numbers, xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Edit:

Change the call 
from `.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=Numbers(), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

to 
`.AutoFilter Field, Numbers, xlFilterValues`

Comment: I was going to use the `Boundaries` variable to find the range of the array. I get  `Compile error: Invalid ParamArray use`, so it didn't work.

Comment: As I wrote, dont use `Boundaries`. Use the paramarray parameter `numbers` in the criteria with `AuthFilter`. Could you post the full code for me to take a look on what is causing the error?

Comment: The full code is posted above for the sub procedure. Here's the call I'm doing for the procedure: `Call FilterWorkbookByServiceCode("example.xls", "Example1", "A11", "O", 3, "99213", "17000", "BOT1")`
The array starts at "99213".

Comment: Change the call `.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=Numbers(), Operator:=xlFilterValues` to `.AutoFilter Field, Numbers, xlFilterValues`

Comment: Shahkalpesh. Could you please post your comment as a answer? I need to mark it as the answer.